# Including external javascript file in html page via src tag

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

[image]

I'm trying out vuejs by following along with the laracasts series of webcasts on this. I'm using netbeans 8.1 as my editor and you can see my file structure above. In https://laracasts.com/series/learning-vuejs/episodes/5 Jeffery Way shows the following code which I have adapted:

```
<head>
    <title>Tasks</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.12/vue.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Sources/app.js"></script>

</head>
```

In the console I see:

```
GET http://localhost:8383/vue1/Sources/app.js net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

I suspect I have the file path wrong. I've been reading http://www.jibbering.com/faq/faq_notes/script_tags.html but have not not come up with an answer. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Assuming the HTML you posted is in the "Site Root" folder, the `src` should be `../Sources/app.js` I would also advise against using spaces in your folder or file names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is "Site Root" a subfolder on the same folder as "Sources"?

If yes, try it out:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="../Sources/app.js"></script>`

Or move Sources dir to inside Site Root.

Comment: I moved the app.js file to the site root directory and changed the code to     <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script> . It now appears to be working - thanks

Comment: You can also move it to a subfolder inside "Site Root" directory. So you access it by doing `<script type="text/javascript" src="foldername/app.js"></script>`.

Comment: Thanks Jefff, I'm not knowledgeable about js, so is the "site root" a common feature of html/js projects? I'm not sure what its purpose is?

Comment: Not really. Only the files inside it are important. It's just the folder where your site is being saved.